# wait for method call to be completed for another call

Tags: angular

I have a method 'getBitesize(id)' and I want to call it twice, with different ids.

This method looks like this

```
 getBitesize(id) {
   //... some logic here
   if(expression) {
     this.updateProgress(params); 
   } else {
     getProgress(params)
   }
}
```

and update Progress

```
 updateProgress(params) {
    if (expression) {
      this.service.updateProgress(params).subscribe(response => {
        this.course = this.course.map(item => {
          if (item.id === params) {
            item.completion = true;
          }
          return item;
        });
        this.getProgress(this.course);
      });
    }
  }
```

here, when I call getBitesize twice, because of the subscribe in updateProgress, the output is:

> getBitesize(1) and THEN getBitesize(0);

```
 if (expression) {
          this.getBitesize(0);
          this.getBitesize(1);
}
```

How can I wait for the first call of getBitesize to be completed in order to make the second call of the method?

Comment: `this.getBitesize(0).then( () => this.getBitesize(1));` ? Not sure what functions u have available to you, can you use resolve? Please provide a reproducable example.

Comment: As written, you can't, because neither `getBitesize` nor `updateProgress` accept a callback or return a promise (which would enable what @Joel suggests) or observable.

Comment: Use async and await  in  function or if you want to use rxjs make it to return observable.